# Generating encoder signal wave form using python

Tags: python, noise, waveform

I am trying to generate the following signals using python in order to test some functions, can anyone help?
 I have looked in the wavegenerator library and used this code

```
t=np.linspace(0,1,500, endpoint=False)
S1=signal.square(2*np.pi*10*t)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.plot(t,S1)
plt.show()
```

but I don't know how to make it look exactly as the signal in the sketch^and I don't know how to specify/characterize the form of the noise:

```
t=np.linspace(0,1,100, endpoint=False)
S1=signal.square(2*np.pi*10*t)
noise = np.random.normal(0,0.05,100)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.plot(t,S1+noise)
plt.show()
```

[Signals sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfsq2.jpg)

Comment: isn't it a triangular waveform on top of a square one, where the frequency of the triangle-function is 10x the square frequency ?

Comment: @Morten Jensen, not exactly a triangular, its supposed to be random noise

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution based from this site : https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/197.php
so this the code that i used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import scipy.integrate
from scipy import signal

t = numpy.arange(0,4,0.001)

# duty cycle on phase A and B
Da = 0.70
Db = 0.40

def extendrange(ra,rb):
    if ra is None:
        return rb
    elif rb is None:
        return ra
    else:
        return (min(ra[0],rb[0]),max(ra[1],rb[1]))

def createLimits(margin, *args):
    r = None
    for x in args:
        r = extendrange(r, (numpy.min(x),numpy.max(x)))
    rmargin = (r[1]-r[0])*margin/2.0
    return (r[0]-rmargin,r[1]+rmargin)

def showripple(centeralign=False):
    # voltage waveforms on phases A and B

    if centeralign:
        sawtooth = abs(2*(t % 1) - 1)
        Va = sawtooth < Da
        Vb = sawtooth < Db
    else:
        ramp = t % 1
        Va = ramp < Da
        Vb = ramp < Db

    # plot results
    margin = 0.1
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    VA=Va*0.8
    VB=Vb*0.8+1
    y = [VA, VB]
    ax.plot(t,y[0],t,y[1])
    ax.set_yticks([0.4,1.4])
    ax.set_yticklabels(['A','B'])
    ax.set_ylim(createLimits(margin,y[0],y[1]))
    ax.set_ylabel('Phase duty cycles')

    #generating noise
   noise = numpy.random.normal(0,0.009,len(VA))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
    y = [VA + noise, VB]
    ax.plot(t,y[0],t,y[1])
    ax.set_yticks([0.4,1.4])
    ax.set_yticklabels(['A','B'])
    ax.set_ylim(createLimits(margin,y[0],y[1]))
    ax.set_ylabel(' Noisy Phase duty cycles')



showripple(centeralign=True)
plt.show()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Exhw.png)